# insert user using seed in asp.net identity tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to insert a record to asp.net identity table structure from code level like following.

```
public class ProjectName_DbInitalize : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProjectName_DBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ProjectName_DBContext context)
    {

        context.AspNetUsers.Add
        (
              new AspNetUser
              {
                  Email = "kez@gmail.com",
                  EmailConfirmed = true,
                  PasswordHash = "123456",
                  SecurityStamp = "Author 1st Bio",
                  PhoneNumber = "0734248148",
                  PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                  LockoutEndDateUtc = null,
                  LockoutEnabled = true,
                  AccessFailedCount = 0,
                  UserName = "",
                  FirstName = "",
                  LastName = "",
                  CreatedBy = "",
                  CreatedDate = null,
                  UpdatedBy = null,
                  UpdatedDate = null

              }
          );

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);

    }

}
```

In unit test project I'm inserting like following

```
public class IdentityRepositoryTest
{
    IdentityRepository identitityRepo;

    // initialize the test class
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        ProjectName_DbInitalize db = new ProjectName_DbInitalize();
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(db);
        identitityRepo = new IdentityRepository();
    }      
}
```

but when I run this, it is not inserting values to `AspNet.Users` Table or any other table, how can I do this properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to not add PasswordHash (I think it do it for you ..cause it need to do the hash and salt it) and then try to put a not empty username (mayb set it equal as email).

Finally try to put it in a try catch so you can debug it and read the exactly error something like this

public class ProjectName_DbInitalize : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProjectName_DBContext context)
        {

```
        try
        {
            context.AspNetUsers.Add
                   (
                         new AspNetUser
                         {
                             Email = "kez@gmail.com",
                             EmailConfirmed = true,
                             PasswordHash = "123456",
                             SecurityStamp = "Author 1st Bio",
                             PhoneNumber = "0734248148",
                             PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                             LockoutEndDateUtc = null,
                             LockoutEnabled = true,
                             AccessFailedCount = 0,
                             UserName = "",
                             FirstName = "",
                             LastName = "",
                             CreatedBy = "",
                             CreatedDate = null,
                             UpdatedBy = null,
                             UpdatedDate = null

                         }
                     );

            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);

            //context.SaveChanges(); 


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```